# How to troubleshoot a hanging cygwin cp running as service

Tags: debugging, cygwin, cp

I have a Windows 7 machine with oldish Hudson running in Glassfish container. This runs a build governed by long cygwin bash script. One part of the script contains a loop:

```
if [ -d "$STASH_DIR" ]; then
    svn status -v images | \
            iconv -f cp1250 -t utf-8 | \
            sed 's+\\+/+g' | \
            grep '^        .*\.\(gif\|png\)$' | \
            while read dummy rev author file; do
        dat=${file%.???}.dat
        if [ -f "$STASH_DIR/$dat.$rev" ]; then
            cp -v "$STASH_DIR/$dat.$rev" "$dat"
        fi
    done || true # Not critical; ignore failures
fi
```

(There is a bunch of images and a process that operates on them and that is very slow, so I cache it's results in a separate directory. The process can probably be made much faster, but that's another issue.)

Now occasionally the `cp`, one somewhere halfway through the list of files, hangs. It goes into infinite loop eating CPU and I have to kill it. When I do, the loop continues and the build finishes fine. But since it is just a cache, if the file didn't copy, the build would still succeed.

So my question is **what options do I have for troubleshooting this**? It is running as service under SYSTEM account, but I do have administrator right, so I might be able to attach something to it. I just don't know what would help. I have Visual Studio there and can install any cygwin tools there, but the binary obviously isn't built with debug information.

**Edit:** I've tried:

- `resmon` shows nothing interesting except that the process is running at full speed.
- It's might be interesting that the processes are reported as being `bash.exe` by windows tools while they are `/usr/bin/cp` according to cygwin's ps.
- According to debugger (Visual Studio) the processes don't have any debug information (expected) and are only executing code from `cygwin1.dll` (the root frame only), `kernel32.dll` and `ntdll.dll`; no frames point to the executable itself.
- According to [`handle.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) only has open a glassfish log file (`C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\jvm.log`), it's working directory and `C:\Windows` and besides that only a bunch of objects called `\BaseNamedObjects\`*something*.

Might be that it fails when trying to execute the `cp.exe` or when it's finishing, but I still don't know how to check it/debug it.

Comment: Since you are on win7 have you tried `resmon.exe` and selecting the hanging process and choosing 'Analyze Wait Chain' ? see this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt_pietrek/archive/2009/04/17/analyze-wait-chain-why-is-my-program-stuck.aspx

Comment: @wal: Not yet; didn't know about it. Thanks.

Comment: @wal: Hm, the problem is that it's live-locked, not dead-locked. So there is no wait chain, because it's not waiting. It's burning CPU like crazy.

Comment: Ok, use Process Hacker to get some more information about the process. I created a sample application that does nothing except lock a file then hang. Right click the process in Process Hacker, select Properties then go to the `Handles` tab, then look at the File handles to get an idea what it might be doing. Heres a screenshot http://www.uploadscreenshot.com/image/750395/3124405
EDIT: ok i just re-read your question and you've checked the handles... its worth using Process Hacker anyway as you can also look at the `Threads` tab which will show you what each is doing.

Comment: @wal: Thanks, I'll try next time it happens.